# How to design database for multivalued attributes?

Tags: sql, database-schema

I have some entities with different kind of attributes.
First, my db schema looks like:

```
tbl_attr
attr_id | user_id | value
```

Where value - string type, contains INT, DATE and STRING values.

Second, i have a function which helps me get attributes

```
FUNCTION get_attr(id int, user_id int)
  RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT tbl_attr.value FROM tst WHERE tbl_attr.user_id = user_id and tbl_attr.attr_id = id);
END
```

So simple aggregation query looks like:

```
Select sum(get_attr(2, 2)), sum(get_attr(3, 2)) from tst where get_attr(2, 2)
Order by get_attr(2, 2) desc
```

Is it right solution for my situation?

UPD: this code didn't work, because i should add CAST to get_attr function for convert string to int or date. This code showed just for explain how my idea should work

Comment: Why would you be calling `sum()` on a function that returns a character string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff update question

Comment: What type of attributes are in play here?

Comment: personally I'd avoid the function. Because functions work row by row, it will cause performance problems, which are not that obvious to find.

Comment: @DanBracuk INT, TEXT and DATETIME

Comment: What would some sample attributes be?